# How to eliminate whitespace between two divs in different class=row's (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

Looks good except for on vertical tablet browsers. Whitespace between red and blue divs appears, forced by the height of the black div.

It's also critical in the solution that the stacking order of divs on tablet/mobile screens goes blue > black > red.

```
            <html>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7"><div class="blue"><img src="jpg"> Lots of whitespace appears below between 768 to aprx 900 px browser width (tablet dimenions)</div></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5"><div class="black">Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text<br>Line of text</div>
            </div>   
            </div>
            </div>     
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-7"><div class="red">Red</div></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5"><div>
            </div>   
            </div>
            </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g7xg0uc7/1/

Comment: What did you expect? Every line is ended with a <br> so the div will move down with each line added.

Answer (score 0):

The `row` with red `div` will be pushed down by the height of the black `div`.

Add the red `div` just below the blue div in the same `col-sm-7` div.

Comment: Can't. It's critical that the stacking order of divs on tablet/mobile screens goes blue > black > red. Your way would result in blue > red > black.

Answer (score 0):

If you change all your `col-sm-#` to `col-md-#` then it takes the whitespace away from the bottom of the image and the red div, but there is still whitespace between the those 2 and the black div full of text.

Try playing with those to see if you can get exactly what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do: https://jsfiddle.net/g7xg0uc7/12/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="blue">
                <img src="https://wiki.creativecommons.org/images/9/97/8256206923_c77e85319e_n.jpg" /> Lots of whitespace appears below between 768 to aprx 900 px browser width (tablet dimenions)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5" style="float: right;">
            <div class="black">
                Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text<br/>Line of text
           </div>     
        </div>   
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="red">Red</div>
        </div>
     </div>   
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.black {width:100%; color: #fff;background-color: black ; padding:10px; float: right;}
.red {width:100%; background-color:red;  color: #fff; padding:10px; float: left;}
.blue {width:100%; background-color:blue; color: #fff; padding:10px}
img {width:100%}
```

Sorry if I removed containers you need, trying to clean up the code to make the answer clear. That inline float can be tidied away into a class if you're averse to inline styling.